# установить приоритет загрузки

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет всем.
Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли установить приоритет загрузки.
Дело в том, что у меня открывается UserControl, на котором стоит фон, PNG формат, и текст.Когда открывается данный контрол, получается маленькое мерцания. Как я думаю что текст загружается быстрей чем картинка. Это не очень красиво. Я конечно, подразумеваю что это можно решить с помощью потоков. Но, надеюсь у вас есть, другой вариант. Спасибо

```
   private void butNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContRegistr contReg = new ContRegistr(); // Ссылка на Контрол
        try
        {
            _view.CloseControl(this); // Закрываю текущий контрол _view ,это класс. CloseControl() метод

            // Цифры в методе, это размер и локация контрола. мне лень постоянно настраивать в ручную
            _view.OpenControl(contReg, 800, 600, 200, 190); // Открываю Новый контрол contReg .


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это у вас WinForms или WPF?

Comment: @VladD WinForms

Answer (score 1):

С помощью потоков это решить нельзя - вся отрисовка должна происходить в главном потоке.

Попробуйте выставить у своего контрола свойство [`DoubleBuffered` в `true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это не помогло. У меня стояло в true

Comment: @ГеннадийПисарев тогда показывайте минимальный код для воспроизведения. Вдруг оно не мерцает, и вам просто кажется :)

Comment: Я добавил код к вопросу